# App error, pushed to heroku Missing template

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, web-applications, cloud

I'm attempting to deploy a rails webapp on Heroku using Cloud9. This might be a precompiling asset problem. I checked the heroku error logs and the error says Action Controller: Exception Caught

Everything works fine on my local machine, there is just something going wrong when pushing to heroku.

```
def find(*args)
          find_all(*args).first || raise(MissingTemplate.new(self, *args))
        end

        def find_all(path, prefixes = [], *args)

vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionview-4.2.4/lib/action_view/path_set.rb:46:in `find'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionview-4.2.4/lib/action_view/lookup_context.rb:121:in `find'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionview-4.2.4/lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:18:in `find_template'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionview-4.2.4/lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:40:in `determine_template'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionview-4.2.4/lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:8:in `render'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionview-4.2.4/lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:42:in `render_template'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionview-4.2.4/lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:23:in `render'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionview-4.2.4/lib/action_view/rendering.rb:100:in `_render_template'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_controller/metal/streaming.rb:217:in `_render_template'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionview-4.2.4/lib/action_view/rendering.rb:83:in `render_to_body'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:32:in `render_to_body'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_controller/metal/renderers.rb:37:in `render_to_body'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:25:in `render'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:16:in `render'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:44:in `block (2 levels) in render'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:12:in `block in ms'
vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/benchmark.rb:296:in `realtime'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:12:in `ms'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:44:in `block in render'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:87:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:25:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:43:in `render'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:10:in `default_render'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:5:in `send_action'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:198:in `process_action'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:20:in `block in process_action'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:117:in `call'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:117:in `call'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:555:in `block (2 levels) in compile'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:505:in `call'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:505:in `call'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:92:in `__run_callbacks__'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:778:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:19:in `process_action'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:32:in `block in process_action'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `block in instrument'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `instrument'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:250:in `process_action'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:137:in `process'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionview-4.2.4/lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_controller/metal.rb:196:in `dispatch'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_controller/metal.rb:237:in `block in action'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:76:in `call'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:76:in `dispatch'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:45:in `serve'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:43:in `block in serve'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in `each'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in `serve'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:821:in `call'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/warden-1.2.3/lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/warden-1.2.3/lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/warden-1.2.3/lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/etag.rb:24:in `call'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/head.rb:13:in `call'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:260:in `call'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:560:in `call'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:653:in `call'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in `__run_callbacks__'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:778:in `_run_call_callbacks'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:78:in `call'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:22:in `call'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/runtime.rb:18:in `call'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:116:in `call'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/sendfile.rb:113:in `call'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:518:in `call'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/application.rb:165:in `call'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/content_length.rb:15:in `call'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:88:in `service'
vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'
```

Comment: have you tried running `rake assets:precompile` before pushing to heroku?

Comment: Just tried it, nothing happened

Comment: You get this error when pushing the repo?